# Desktop from work does not work at home

Tags: networking

Like many of you I had to take computers home and work from there. I have only Linux, since I always automatically uninstall Windows when I buy a PC. Both my laptops work with the Xfinity router/modem.

The desktop, connected to the back of it, does not. I see from ifconfig -a that my eth0: inet and broadcast addresses are from my work domain. What do I need to do to make it work?

(I also have an old Minimac which has some useful software. Not tried yet to connect it. I assume it is the same fix)

I solved it. From Settings -> Network, click on the + button to generate a new connection. Make this automatic for IPv4 and IPv6. The unclick "connect automatically" in the previous one and click it in the new one. Not sure it will work with my VPN towards Japan, where I often work, but this will be for tomorrow.
Thanks to all.

lsb_release -a

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Does the PC have a static IP assigned for the work network?

Comment: Yes, since those eth0: inet and broadcast addresses are from my work domain, they must be static.

Comment: Seems like you must change the network settings on *either* your home router or your PC to be compatible with the other.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the entire output of `lsb_release -a` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thanks, as copied from my Linux box (which is not on the internet), lsb_release -a gives Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic. Sorry for the formatting, it is not letting me use return without kicking me out of the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your desktop has a static IP that is not within your router's subnet.

In plain English: your desktop has an network address that's not within your router's range of addresses, so they can't see each other.

You'll have to switch the desktop to DHCP first. Or change the router's subnet to match the desktop's then reboot all the other clients so they pick up new IP addresses in that subnet from the router.

To me, this sounds like poor planning from your IT department. Most corporate static IPs are 10.x.x.x while most home IP addresses are 192.168.1/0.x. This means that in most cases a desktop taken directly from work won't work at home without some reconfig that end users are most likely unfamiliar with.